# Backbone model in form submit event

Tags: backbone.js, underscore.js

It seems that this.model return an undefined in the form submit event function, even after I do the _bindall(). Render function is ok.

```
initialize: function() {
  _.bindAll(
    this, 
    "render", 
    "processFormEditJobSubmit"
  );
},
```

Form submit event:

```
processFormEditJobSubmit: function(e) {  
  e.preventDefault();
  e.stopImmediatePropagation();
  console.log(this.model); //undefined
}
```

How to solve this? Or did I do wrong with the binding? I prolly will just serialize the model in the sessionStorage and deserialize it in the submit function. I prefer to avoid hacking in my code. Thank you for any pointers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no error in the code you've shown, but the example is incomplete, Here's a working code snippet:

```js
var MyView = Backbone.View.extend({

  el: '#view',

  events: {
    'click button.a': 'processFormEditJobSubmit'
  },

  initialize: function() {
    _.bindAll(
      this,
      "render",
      "processFormEditJobSubmit"
    );
  },
  
  render: function() {
    this.$('button.b').click(this.processFormEditJobSubmit);
  },

  processFormEditJobSubmit: function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopImmediatePropagation();
    console.log(this.model.get('prop')); //not undefined
  }

});

new MyView({
  model: new Backbone.Model({prop: 'here'})
}).render();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/underscore.js/1.8.3/underscore-min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/backbone.js/1.3.3/backbone-min.js"></script>

<div id="view">
  <button class="a">
    event hash
  </button>
  <button class="b">
    jquery handler
  </button>
</div>
```

If there's something I've missed, say so and I'll update the snippet.